# How to select all elements of body except one in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<body>.
    <section class="apply-me1">.

    </section>.

    <section class="apply-me2">.

    </section>.

    <a class="except-me" href="#">Something here</a>.
</body>
```

Now I want to apply some rules on all elements except the a tag using css and javascript not jquery.

I Tried this:

CSS:

```css
body {
    some rules here
}

body >*:not(.except-me).active {
    some rules here
}
```

Javascript:

```js
selectBody = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];

selectBody.addEventListener('click', () => {

    selectBody.classList.toggle('active');

})
```

Basically I want to switch classes on body so some rules can be applied on all elements except the a tag when I click on body.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). What you must pass in the braces is a css selector. a sample here :

```
document.querySelector('body >*:not(.except-me).active');
```

This will help you a lot. Don't forget that you **MUST** put a css selector in the braces.